# flip css for right to left (rtl) languages

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

Note: I'm open to other solutions if this is the wrong approach

> I want to used https://github.com/twitter/css-flip for rtl support on
>   my project

The documentation is sparse and seems to make a lot of assumptions. I can successfully run the CLI against a .css file but not a scss file as I suspected.

I was thinking about adding a step that ran the css-flip on the compiled styles like so:

css-flip app/assets/stylesheets/application.css > app/assets/stylesheets/application.rtl.css

One, I'm not sure this is the best approach, and Two, if it is reasonable, how could I run the css-flip command on the assets after they've been compiled?

Comment: why not just use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right approach, but I'd say you can use css-flip to generate your css files, and afterwards, I see 2 different solutions. (In the case you don't want to use Pete suggestion about the [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) property, but I assume you may want some custom style depending of the orientation of the language.)

1 - depending on the version of your site, you change the asset being loaded.

2 - Or, I'd say you concat your two css files generated to put both behind a class (probably with the help of a preprocessor such as [sass](https://sass-lang.com/guide)), and you put this class on your body, and change it whenever the user changes their language settings.

solution 1 creates lighter css file, but your user need to reload the page when they change language, whereas solution 2 creates bigger css file, but user won't need to reload their page when they change language.

Hope this helps.